# Python: for loop that drops a column to meet condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
alpha_0  alpha_1  alpha_2  alpha_3
1        2        1        4
2        0        3        8
0        0        0        9
```

Beta is calculated as ((sum of each row)^2)/10.  I want to keep dropping columns until Beta is less than or equal to 1 for all rows.

So far I have

```
n_alphas=4
for alpha in range(0,n_alphas):
    df.drop(list(values.filter(regex = 'alpha '+str(alpha))), axis = 1, 
    inplace = True)
    
    Beta=(df.sum(axis=1)^2)/10
    print(Beta)
```

How can I stop the loop when all values of beta are below or equal to 1?

Comment: what is the exact formula for beta?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here

Comment: Yes. Please be more specific @Niam45

Comment: If possible please provide the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to calculate the power of a number, do not use `^` operator. It is an XOR Boolean operator. Instead, use `**` operator.

This code should work. However, this will also delete last remaining column from the dataframe, if the condition of Beta is not met.

```
for column in df.columns:
    Beta = (df.sum(axis=1) ** 2) / 10
    if Beta.min() > 1.0:
        df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)
```

If you do not want the last remaining column to be deleted even if the Beta condition is not met, use this code

```
n_alphas = 4
for alpha in range(0, n_alphas):
    Beta = (df.sum(axis=1) ** 2) / 10
    if Beta.min() > 1.0:
        df.drop(columns=[f"alpha_{alpha}"], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you expecting for this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [1,2,0],'a2':[2,0,0],'a3':[1,3,0],'a4':[4,8,9]})
for i in range(len(df)):
    if sum(df.iloc[i])**2 /10 > 1:
        df = df.drop([df.columns[0]], axis=1)
```